# ModelAndView or ResponseEntity return type for controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, controller

So far in my experience with Spring I have mainly seen `ResponseEntity` return types for controllers. However, I have seen `ModelAndView` return types. Why would someone use `ModelAndView` over `ResponseEntity` or vice versa?

In other words, what are the benefits and negatives of either, as I can't really find a comparison of such online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ResponseEntity is used for RestController, where you want to return a response (200, 400, etc..) with a payload (Json, etc..).

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello World!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

ModelAndView is used for MVC Controller, where you return the view (HTML, jsp, etc..) templates with data fields set to values you fill the templates with.

Example: an HTML page named *employeeDetails* with two fields (*employeeObj, msg*)

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("employeeDetails");
model.addObject("employeeObj", new EmployeeBean(123));
model.addObject("msg", "Employee information.");
return model;
```

Comment: Okay that makes more sense to me, however I fail to see why you would use the ModelAndView for REST apis.

Comment: You wouldn't use the ModelAndView for APIs.

Comment: Thank you, that was my suspicion. Accepted as the answer.